# Firebase gets stuck on no INTERNET connection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app, I am using Firebase for database. Now when I am listening for any change in child nodes of a particular location, and if there is no internet connection, no callback gets fired. The firebase call just gets stuck.

I am using this,

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
firebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

So, persistence is enabled. The problem occurs only one one scenario. When there is no data on the local persistence of Firebase and the internet connection is also not available.

I am using this,

```
addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Timber.d("Cancelled");
                        }
                    });
```

I am not getting any of the two callbacks for that particular scenario.

What should I do to tackle this kind of scenario?

Comment: I'm actually experiencing this same problem right now. Did you do anything to solve it? If not, then I might have to resort to their REST API.

Comment: What SDK version are you using for Firebase?

Comment: I ended up solving the issue by using the information I got from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021378/android-firebase-ondatachange-and-oncancelled-not-being-called-with-no-int/39021671#39021671

Comment: Thanks. It would be great if you can put your solution as an answer. Can be helpful for everyone else.

Answer (score 9):

Let's see how those methods are triggered when there is no connectivity:

`onCancelled` - when there is a server-side error. For example, when the user doesn't have access to the specified node. (Or when you reach the connection limit on the Sparkle plan).

`onDataChange` - if there is data persisted, it will read this data. If not, this method won't be triggered (your case).

According to the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state), If you want to check if the device is connected to the Firebase Server, you can add a listener to `.info/connected`. Like this:

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
    if (connected) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toask.LENGTH_SHORT);
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Not connected", Toask.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
  }
});
```

Comment: i wonder from where you known that we need to fetch this reference '.info/connected 'to check connection status.

Comment: I have added the Firebase documentation link to my answer. @Herry

Comment: `connected` is false even if Internet is available