# Cloud Firestore doesn't have 'goOffline', 'goOnline' methods. (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, connection, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase Realtime database has a function `goOffline`, `goOnline` which can manage the connection manually. But, Firestore doesn't have these methods.

Does Firestore return exception something like `NETWORK_ERROR` when device lost connection with server? If it doesn't, how can I manage Firestore connection manually when device can't connect to internet and reconnected. (e.g. Airplane mode, Bad wifi)

In my case, I don't use `persistence mode`.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Firestore return exception something like NETWORK_ERROR when
>   device lost connection with server?

You have use [addOnFailureListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#addOnFailureListener(android.app.Activity,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener)) which uses [OnFailureListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/OnFailureListener) that can just gives you an `Exception` object to find the cause or message behind the exception via [getCause](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause()) or [getMessage](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage()) and further can apply String checks like contains etc to verify the cause but currently there is no standard way provided by FirebaseFirestore.

> how can I manage Firestore connection manually when device can't connect to internet and reconnected. (e.g. `Airplane mode, Bad wifi`)

[`You can check the connectivity yourself also at desired places before executing firebase code`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android)

Comment: Thanks for detail answer. So you mean `Firestore` changed `onCancelled`'s behavior [which didn't support on `Realtime database`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39021378/4729203)?

Comment: And actually there is no `onCancelled` method in `Firestore`. Where can I find this callback?

Comment: @wonsuc you have two situations, first, no network (you can check the connectivity yourself , check the link in second part) and in case of network error refter the first part

Comment: you want to check the network error for firebaseStorage? if yes then let me check it

Comment: Sorry, I'm asking about [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/).

Comment: @wonsuc could you add some code to explain it more about what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: I will add more detail example code to my question later. Thanks for attention.

Comment: @wonsuc welcome, if you have `onevent` with `firebasefirestoneexception` you can verify the error using [FirebaseFirestoreException.Code enum values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code) although there is no direct network error but others can be helpful