# Firebase listener not getting called

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> I want to check whether node is created or not. I just implemented below called with Toast but nothing toasting at all.

**note: firebase DataBase is Total null now**

```
  DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, dataSnapshot.getKey() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, databaseError.toString() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

*secondly below code i tried but no luck*

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    reference.child("device_id");

    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, dataSnapshot.getKey() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, databaseError.toString() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
```

Comment: "firebase DataBase is Total null now" - does that mean you don't have any data on your database?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41832659/5861618)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code:

```
reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

with:

```
reference.child("device_id").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```